# VB6 with MAPI for Lotus Notes

Tags: vb6, lotus-notes, mapi

Everybody,

I need to incorporate mail functionality into a VB6 application. The default mail system is Lotus Notes 6.5. I have read that this version of Lotus Notes is MAPI-enabled.

Here is a weird thing I see. When the user clicks a SendMail button, the below code is launched:

```
 MAPISession1.SignOn
With MAPIMessages1
    .SessionID = MAPISession1.SessionID
    .Compose
    .RecipAddress = "John Smith"
    .MsgSubject = "Test memo"
    .MsgNoteText = "This is testing data!"
    .AddressResolveUI = True
    .ResolveName
    .Send True
End With
```

This code opens a window in Lotus Notes (this is what I expected) but
- the To address box contains the recipient address followed by the body text on the first line and the recipient address on the second line:

```
John SmithThis is testing data!
John Smith
```

-- the Body section is blank.

Is there anything I can do to fix it or Lotus Notes is incompatible with MAPI.
Thanks,
Lev

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the appropriate tools, so I can't test this, but try moving the `.ResolveName` line up right after you set the recipient address, like so:

```
.Compose
.RecipAddress = "John Smith"
.ResolveName
```

Lotus Notes is compatible with Simple MAPI, not full (extended) MAPI, but the code you're using appears to be Simple MAPI.

Comment: Joel, I've tried your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't help. More ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick bit of research and supposedly Simple MAPI is supported in Lotus Notes 6.  However, a little more digging led me to [this post](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/41326.aspx) where someone had trouble using MAPI in r6, and opted to use COM instead.  I've only worked with COM, but I can say it does give you a lot of flexibility if you're up for changing your code.

Comment: Can you please specify what COM do you have in mind: CDO, Winsock, anything else? Thanks.

Comment: I'm referring to the Lotus Notes COM API.  Here's an example:  http://www.fabalou.com/VBandVBA/lotusnotesmail.asp.